# Váriavel em PHP pode começar com underline?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se uma variável em `php` pode começar com `underline`, por exemplo: `$_1teste;`

Comment: [Manual do PHP>Referência da Linguagem>Variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: Não é obrigatório mas pode!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: Esse tipo de pergunta eu fecharia, como "preguiça".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim. Pode sim!

Segundo a [documentação oficial do PHP sobre variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php):

> "Um nome de variável válido inicia-se com uma letra ou sublinhado"

Exemplos:

```
$4site = 'not yet';     // inválido; começa com um número
$_4site = 'not yet';    // válido; começa com um sublinhado
$täyte = 'mansikka';    // válido; 'ä' é um caracter ASCII (extendido) 228
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode sim, as variaveis podem começar com uma letra ou sublinhado.

Por exemplo:

```
// Variaveis validas;
$_variavel = 'valor';
$_2variavel = 'valor';
$_1234_vel = 'valor';

// Variaveis não validas;
$+variavel = 'valor';
$-2variavel = 'valor';
$?1234_vel = 'valor';
```

Até mais!

Answer (score 1):

Sim, em php estas são as regras.

Consulte [documentação oficial do PHP sobre variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php):

> "Um nome de variável válido inicia-se com uma letra ou sublinhado"

Exemplos:

```
  // Variaveis validas;
   $_variavel = 'valor';
   $_2variavel = 'valor';
   $_1234_vel = 'valor';

    // Variaveis não validas;
    $+variavel = 'valor';
    $-2variavel = 'valor';
    $?1234_vel = 'valor';
```

[Consulte tambem este link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php)